# setting up bind9 on ubuntu

Tags: dns, syslog, bind

I am trying to set up bind9 on my ubuntu server behind a linksys router at home. I followed the many tutorials/articles online, but It still seems not to be working. 
Here is my `named.conf`.options:

```
acl "trusted" {
    192.168.1.129; # geppubuntu (local dns)
    192.168.1.140; # printer
    192.168.1.100; # other ubuntu
    192.168.1.1  ; # router
};
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind/";


forwarders {        
    8.8.8.8;
    8.8.4.4;        
};

recursion yes;
allow-recursion {trusted; };
listen-on {192.168.1.129; };        
allow-transfer {none; };    

dnssec-validation auto;

auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

Then I have my `named.conf.local`

```
zone "mainserver.geppo" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zone/db.mainserver.geppo";      
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.192";  
};
```

here are my `db.mainserver.geppo` file

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA geppubuntu.mainserver.geppo. admin.mainserver.geppo. (
           20160821     ; Serial
         604800     ; Refresh
          86400     ; Retry
        2419200     ; Expire
         604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
IN  NS  geppubuntu.mainserver.geppo.

geppubuntu.mainserver.geppo.      IN      A       192.168.1.129

router.mainserver.geppo.          IN      A       192.168.1.1
geppubuntus1.mainserver.geppo.    IN      A       192.168.1.100
printer.mainserver.geppo.         IN      A       192.168.1.140
```

and `db.192`

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA geppubuntu.mainserver.geppo. admin.mainserver.geppo. (
        20160821    ; Serial
         604800     ; Refresh
          86400     ; Retry
        2419200     ; Expire
         604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
IN  NS  geppubuntu.

129     IN      PTR     geppubuntu.mainserver.geppo.
1       IN      PTR     router.mainserver.geppo.
100     IN      PTR     geppubuntus1.mainserver.geppo.
140     IN      PTR     printer.mainserver.geppo.
```

if I run `sudo named-checkconf`, no issues
if I run `sudo named-checkzone mainserver.main /etc/bind/zones/db.mainserver.geppo`, I see the following :

```
 zone mainserver.geppo/IN: loaded serial 20160821
OK
```

if I run `sudo named-checkzone mainserver.main /etc/bind/zones/db.192`, I see the following :

```
zone mainserver.geppo/IN: loaded serial 20160821
OK
```

however, I can ping and nslookup the IP addresses, for instance, if I run

```
nslookup 192.168.1.129
```

This is what I see
    Server:     192.168.1.129
    Address:    192.168.1.129#53
    129.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa  name = geppubuntu.mainserver.geppo.

I can ping the names, but I cannot nslookup

```
nslookup geppubuntu.mainserver.geppo
```

This is what I see

```
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 192.168.1.129, trying next server
Server:     75.75.75.75
Address:    75.75.75.75#53

** server can't find geppubuntu.mainserver.geppo: NXDOMAIN
```

Also if I look at the `/etc/var/syslog` file looking for bind9 issues, I can read few lines saying

```
 Aug 21 16:18:45 geppubuntu named[5662]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN:   
 loaded serial 1
 Aug 21 16:18:45 geppubuntu named[5662]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: 
 loaded serial 1
 Aug 21 16:18:45 geppubuntu named[5662]: zone localhost/IN: loaded 
 serial 2
 Aug 21 16:18:45 geppubuntu named[5662]: zone 1.168.192.in-  
 addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 20160821
 Aug 21 16:18:45 geppubuntu named[5662]: zone mainserver.geppo/IN: 
 loading from master file /etc/bind/zone/db.mainserver.geppo failed: 
 file not found
 Aug 21 16:18:45 geppubuntu named[5662]: zone mainserver.geppo/IN: not 
 loaded due to errors.
 Aug 21 16:18:45 geppubuntu named[5662]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN:     
 loaded serial 1
 Aug 21 16:18:45 geppubuntu named[5662]: all zones loaded
 Aug 21 16:18:45 geppubuntu named[5662]: running
 Aug 21 16:18:45 geppubuntu named[5662]: zone 1.168.192.in-
 addr.arpa/IN:     
 sending notifies (serial 20160821)
```

I have been struggling for a while now, nay help would be really appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

If I run `named-checkzone`, the way you wrote it, on your file I get a bunch of errors:

```
$ sudo named-checkzone mainserver.main db.mainserver.geppo.original
db.mainserver.geppo.original:11: ignoring out-of-zone data (geppubuntu.mainserver.geppo)
db.mainserver.geppo.original:13: ignoring out-of-zone data (router.mainserver.geppo)
db.mainserver.geppo.original:14: ignoring out-of-zone data (geppubuntus1.mainserver.geppo)
db.mainserver.geppo.original:15: ignoring out-of-zone data (printer.mainserver.geppo)
zone mainserver.main/IN: has no NS records
zone mainserver.main/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

If I run `named-checkzone`, the way I think it should be run, I still get errors:

```
$ sudo named-checkzone mainserver.geppo db.mainserver.geppo.original
zone mainserver.geppo/IN: has no NS records
zone mainserver.geppo/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

If I fix the file and then run `named-checkzone`, it seems O.K.:

```
$ sudo named-checkzone mainserver.geppo db.mainserver.geppo.doug
zone mainserver.geppo/IN: loaded serial 20160821
OK
```

The file, db.mainserver.geppo.doug:

```
$TTL    604800
@               IN      SOA mainserver.geppo. admin.mainserver.geppo. (
                20160821        ; Serial
                604800          ; Refresh
                86400           ; Retry
                2419200         ; Expire
                604800 )        ; Negative Cache TTL
                IN      A       192.168.1.129
;
@               IN      NS      geppubuntu.mainserver.geppo.
geppubuntu      IN      A       192.168.1.129

router          IN      A       192.168.1.1
geppubuntus1    IN      A       192.168.1.100
printer         IN      A       192.168.1.140
```

Comment: Doug, thanks for your reply. Yes, I posted it wrong, it should have been in both cases : sudo named-checkzone mainserver.geppo /etc/bind/zones/db.mainserver.geppo  and sudo named-checkzone mainserver.main /etc/bind/zones/db.192

Comment: @geppo: Does using my file solve your problem, or do you still have a problem that you still need/want help with?

Comment: Doug, thank you again for your help. I am doing this on my spare time, so it took a while to implement, your suggested changes. Also I realized that I made a mistake in the folder names. At any rate, it works ! I will +1 you suggestion right away !